# Regular expression not working in python. Deleting whitespace at the begining of each line

Tags: python, regex

I have a variable text (in Python) with the text that should be printed in a file and it has a lot of variable length, extra whitespace at the beginning of most lines. All I want to do is delete these spaces. This is the code I used.

```
text = re.sub(r'(^\s*)',r'',text,re.MULTILINE)
```

However only the whitespace of the very first line is erased. Everything else remains as is. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fourth parameter of [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) is replace count, not flag.

> re.sub(pattern, repl, string, **count=0**, flags=0)

```
>>> re.MULTILINE
8
>>> print re.sub(r'(^\s*)', '', '  a\n  b\n', re.MULTILINE)
a
  b
```

Use keyword argument `flags`.

```
>>> print re.sub(r'(^\s*)', '', '  a\n  b\n', flags=re.MULTILINE)
a
b
```

BTW, you don't need parentheses:

```
>>> print re.sub(r'^\s*', '', '  a\n  b\n', flags=re.MULTILINE)
a
b
```

---

Using [`str.lstrip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.lstrip), you don't need regular expression.

```
>>> print '\n'.join(map(str.lstrip, '   a\n   b\n'.splitlines()))
a
b
```

Comment: Also it's worth noting that `str.lstrip` method instead of regex's.

Comment: @utdemir, `str.lstrip` strip only the leading spaces.

Comment: Doesn't thats what the OP want?

Comment: @utdemir, No, OP wants remove **extra whitespace at the beginning of most lines.** That's why OP used `MULTILINE` flags.

Comment: @utdemir, Just added `str.lstrip` + `.splitlines` version.

Comment: This did what I wanted but (I used the last line) also removed all extra \n making the whole text a complete block. Nonetheless I've marked it as a correct answer because the question was with RegExp. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @user792589, The last code remove only last trailing newline. If you wnat keep the last trailing newline, use `.split('\n')` instead of `.splitlines()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this to avoid Regexs

```
text = '\n'.join([line.lstrip() for line in text.splitlines()])
```

This will split into lines, strip the leading whitespace off and combine it back again. Just an alternative solution. I like to avoid Regexs where I can. But other people love them.

Answer (score 0):

Why not writing it with [`lstrip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) to your filestream?

```
file.write(content.lstrip())
```

Assuming, that you itereate through your text, writing it line by line, it would come nearly at no cost.

Answer (score 0):

The gain in performance by avoiding regexes may not outweight code readability unless you're doing this over huge texts all the time. Otherwise, using the regex may just yield to code that is easier to understand:

```
sample_text = "    lorem ipsum\n" * 10
beginning_whitespace = re.compile(r'^\s+', flags=re.MULTILINE)
new_text = re.sub(beginning_whitespace, '', sample_text)
```

than the, sort of cryptic, other options:

```
new_text = '\n'.join([line.lstrip() for line in sample_text.split('\n')])
new_text = '\n'.join(map(str.lstrip, sample_text.splitlines()))
```